# Facebook "Overlay" is in the Background

Tags: facebook, overlay, z-index, facebook-sharer

Hy!, i have an Like, and Send Button on my Page.
When i click on "send", there comes an Overlay, with the Preview of the text to send.
The Overlay, is in the Background partially, how can i change this?

[image: DEMO]

Sorry for my Bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That calendar part of the page has too high of a z-index.  Find it and lower it.  Or put the like box inside a div with a higher z-index.

Comment: I set the z-Index from the div to 999.
The z-index from the calendar is 1.
All other z-indexes, are lower then 500. So, the z-index Option doesnt work :(